# Extending existing jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have an existing jQuery plugin, now I want to extend it. Consider the below mentioned plugin:

```
$.fn.x = function(option) {
        var defaults = {
            a: 1,
            b: 2
        };

        option = $.extend(def, option);
        function abc() {
            //do something
        }
        function def() {
            //do something
        }
    };
```

Now the above one is the plugin I got from somewhere. I need to have custom behavior for abc method, say

```
function abc() {
                //do something else
            }
```

I don't want to change the existing plugin, Can you tell me how could I achieve the same by extending the same or by making my own custom plugin ?

Comment: For information on the difficulty of extending without changing plugins, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050985/best-way-to-extend-a-jquery-plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to replace/override the method in this particular situation because it is declared as a local variable. The best solution would be to write your own plugin, or extend this one with an option for `abc` function.
Something like this:

```
function abc() {
    if(!!option.abc){
         return option.abc.call(this);    
    }
    alert('old abc');
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain " or extend this one with an option for abc function" , I don't want to touch the exisiting plugin.

Comment: @Rocky Singh - I don't see a way around it because of how the plugin is written. You will need to write your own, or find a different plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Think what you're looking for is [jQuery extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

```
newFunctionality = {
    abc: function (){
        alert('yo');
    }
}

$.extend($.fn.x, newFunctionality);
$.fn.x.abc() #=> 'yo'
```