# How to create a jQuery plugin which uses another one?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using the weekCalendar plugin, but I don't really want a week calendar, so I need to modify the original code.

However I'd prefer to create another plugin and modify only the method that I need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050985/best-way-to-extend-a-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to use the original plugin, then there's no reason not to create a new one based on the original. Including both only adds unnecessary overhead to your application.

It is very important that you only modify the code under the license that it is protected under, for legal reasons. This normally means that you will need to credit the original author and include a reference to their license. You should also make it clear that your version is a modification and not the original.

If you really want to include the original (or if it's license prohibits you from modifying the code), then you can simply replace the function that you are interested in as long as it is accessible in the global namespace. It's possible that it is accessible (not all plugins are written "properly," after all) though, so this solution is conditionally acceptable.

Comment: What I really want is to modify a week calendar so I use itd facilitys but my data is the same every week... Was esier that way but some private function needed to be modify... So I use $.extend($.plugin.prototype, arraywithmodification)... My plan was't really creat a new plugin... Anyway, thanks for the aswer