# Encapsulate fullcalendar in my own plugin

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm actually working on a project that used FullCalender and I would liked to add additional functionalities like implementing websocket in the event's fetching process, using handlebars template engine for event's rendering etc. without modifying it's source code.

There a is post about this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050985/best-way-to-extend-a-jquery-plugin) and it's seems that there was no proper solution.

I'm new to the JavaScript world and if someone would be grateful if someone have some examples of website that explained how to accomplish this.

Thank you for your answer !

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: I don't think you can use plugins for fullcalendar so either edit the source or make a new jquery plugin?

Comment: What additional functionality are you talking about? If you can give specific examples or requirements, people can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

All of what you want to do is already available functionality within the plugin itself... Check out the documentation at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/ Look at the eventRender callback to add more info about the event and look at the eventSources for multiple sources, then the event source objects to differentiate them by color. As for the handlebars, im not sure what that is, but there is probably a way to include it. Look at the docs