# jquery plugin code separate multiple files

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, extend

I'm trying to write a simple jquery plugin but code gets huge and messy
below is a portion to explain the idea I'm trying to achieve.

```
(function( $ ) {


 $.fn.pageBuilder = function( options ) {

    var lb = $.extend({

        self:                   this,
        modal_edit:             $("#vz_edit_modal"),
        modal_delete:           $("#vz_delete_modal"),
        onSlideElements:        function() {},
        onInsertElement:        function() {},
        onSaveElement:          function() {},

    }, options);


    // Disabling all link clicks default action within page layout builder
    this.on( 'click', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });


    // Changing class of layout builder elements while dragging for cursor change purposes
    this.on('mousedown', '.element .inner', function(){
        $(this).addClass('grabbing');
    }).on('mouseup', '.element .inner', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('grabbing');
    });     
 };

}( jQuery ));
```

So this code is core of plugin and want to keep in jquery.myplugin.js
and now when I try to create a new file jquery.myplugin.elements.js and add this code:

```
(function( $ ){

 $.extend($.fn, {

    pageBuilder: function( options ){ 

        // Extended action
        this.find(".element a").on('click', function() {
            console.log( lb.modal_edit ); // Access to core plugin option
        });
    }

 });

})( jQuery );
```

The matter is I can't get the extended plugin working, the this.find(".element a").on('click', function() { doesn't work, I mean console.log is never fired weather can't get access to lb.modal_edit or extending in wrong way...

Also I need both of functionality to work the core plugin and the extended one, extending plugin shouldn't deactivate core functions..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't seem getting it working...

Comment: Get what working? You've not explained what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Just edited the question sorry for frustration, the event is not getting fired from extended plugin..

Comment: Silly question, but... you have both files included in your webpage?

Comment: Yeah I did stuck on this 2 hours or more I'm tryin it in local server :S

Comment: Yeah tried that however, also tried the core and easiest access by trying to console log it, tried this,parent but no chance.

Comment: Hi Richard I do use firebug and I don't think the coma is causing the matter browser in use is firefox. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you could take.  First, you could pass another option to your core plugin that would allow you to execute a callback function.

The second approach would be to [extend the *prototype*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414356/425809) of the core plugin.  Like this:

```
$.fn.pageBuilder.prototype.newFunction = function() {};
```

As for the lb variable, to get access to it, you'll need to expose it in your core plugin, since it's an internal variable.

```
this.lb = lb;
```

(Not sure if that would work exactly as is, but you need to expose it somehow.)

Comment: Thought it will do the trick I defined this.lb = lb; but this is what I get on firebug:

TypeError: this.lb is undefined
console.log( this.lb.modal_edit )

Comment: By the link you've provided, when do the showid get fired?
I applied the code but no activity in console of firebug...

Comment: Functions in javascript are not inherently extendable.  Id Est: You can't add code to the end of a function.  The core plugin is a function (that sets attributes on `this`, which are accessible).  To extend the "pageBuilder" plugin, you have to add new functions to it.  For this "newFunction()" above, you will have to call it explicitly from somewhere.

Comment: So how do I call newFunction() on core plugin or should I call it on creating instance ?

Comment: From the core function, I would recommend passing the function in as another option.  However, you could also do something like: `if (typeof this.newFunction() !== "undefined") { this.newFunction()}` (or whatever the syntax is for dynamic invocation)