# Insert Method into jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am wanting to add a `refresh` function to a jQuery plugin so that I can do

```
$(selector).tooltipster("refresh")
```

I've been trying to use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414356/123415 but without success. This is what I'm trying:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend(true, $[ "fn" ][ "tooltipster" ].prototype, {
        refresh: function() {
          this._update(this.Content);
        },
    });
})(jQuery);
```

For reference, the plugin's code declares `_update` inside of

```
(function ($, window, document) {
  Plugin.prototype = {
    _update: function() {
      /* update code */
    }
  }
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

I'm trying to extend [tooltipster](https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/blob/master/js/jquery.tooltipster.js) I think I've included all the necessary code above though.

The problem seems to be that the Plugin's methods are all within Plugin.prototype which I can't seem to access. As it stands, I'm just getting "Cannot set property 'refresh' of undefined" in the console.

**Update** If I run `$.fn.tooltipster.prototype` in the console, I get

```
- $.fn.(anonymous function) {refresh: function}
  + constructor: function () {
  + refresh: function () {
  + __proto__: Object
```

Implying that I have added refresh somewhere on tooltipster but not where it's meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just set it straight on the prototype?

`$.someplugin.someMethod = function(){}`

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot set property 'refresh' of undefined"

Comment: What are you trying to set refreshed on, can you post full code?

Comment: I'm extending tooltipster (https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/blob/master/js/jquery.tooltipster.js) and I'm trying to add exactly that refresh method.