# How to extend jquery-comments plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using this jquery-comments plugin:

https://github.com/Viima/jquery-comments/blob/master/js/jquery-comments.js

I'd like to extend the plugin with my own functionality. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050985/best-way-to-extend-a-jquery-plugin), I can use the $.extend approach:

```
(function($) {
/**
 *  Namespace: the namespace the plugin is located under
 *  pluginName: the name of the plugin
 */
    var extensionMethods = {
        /*
         * add own functions here
         */
        myFunction: function(){
            ...
        }
    };

    $.extend(true, $[ Namespace ][ pluginName ].prototype, extensionMethods);


})(jQuery);
```

But how should I set $extend here with namespace and pluginName, to actually extend jquery-comments?

**UPDATE:**

I got it to work writing this in $.extend:

```
$.extend(true, $('.jquery-comments').data('comments'), extensionMethods);
```

Thanks to @charlietfl for his helpful comments.

Comment: Depends what you are specifically trying to accomplish and how you want to use whatever you intent to add

Comment: I want my own functions to have access to the "this" in jquery-comments, for example so I can add comments programmatically.

Comment: The way plugin is written could extend the object stored in `$('#comment-container').data('comments')`